# Celui que je t'ai parlé

Tags: grammaire

Dans *Jean de Florette*, on dit parfois « parler qqch à qqn », comme dans cette phrase-ci :

[image: citation du livre]

> Mon petit, que je t'ai parlé hier

Pourquoi *que* et non *dont* ? Est-ce-qu'il s'agit d'un régionalisme ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C'est ici un provençalisme. En provençal (et plus généralement en occitan), ***dont*** est rendu par ***que***:

*L'ome **que** parlavon* : L'homme **dont** on parlait.
*Es uno causo **que** l'on se mesfiso* : C'est une chose **dont** on se méfie.
*Dóu tems **que** vous parle* : Au temps **dont** je vous parle.

Source: [*Founetico*](http://lengo.hb-prov.fr/dico/founetico.pdf), Bertrand de la Tour d'Auvergne.

On rencontre aussi cet usage ailleurs en français très relâché, il est fustigé mais courant en particulier chez les plus jeunes.

Comment: Alors, ce n'est que le pronom *dont* qui est changé ? C'est-à-dire que, si ce n'était pas inverti, il aurait dit "je t'ai parlé de mon petit" ?

Comment: Oui, *de* est utilisé en provençal comme en français : *T'ai parla **de** moun pitchoun*. PS: *inversé*, pas *inverti* !

Answer (score -4):

C'est du très mauvais français, en fait c'est incorrect, mais occasionnellement quelqu'un (très peu instruit) qui ne se soucie pas trop de sa grammaire utilisera ce pronom. Le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/que) n'est pas, à mon avis, assez sévère en se limitant à la spécification « populaire ». Quelque chose comme « Pop., grammaticalement incorrect » aurait été plus approprié. Le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/que#fr-pronom-rel) ne mentionne pas cet usage.

> **4.** Pop. [Empl. de relatif « universel » et de relatif « décumulé »]
> **a)** [Relatif « universel »: que se substitue à qui, dont, auquel, etc.]
> •  C'est toi que j'ai besoin.
> • C'est moi que je lui piquais ses épingles (Labiche, Station Champb., 1862, ii, 1, p. 264).
> • Moi, j' m'en aperçois bien!... sans parler qu'il est raide comme la justice, c'est moi que je lui mets son papier Fayard, qu'on dirait un vieux mur couvert d'affiches... et c' qu'il est maigre! (Gyp, Souv. pte fille, 1927, p. 223).

Comme *Jean de Florette* a été écrit par Pagnol c'est un usage qui s'étend probablement au moins à la Provence. Comme Gyp et Labiche sont des auteurs parisiens, on doit aussi trouver cet usage populaire  dans le Bassin parisien.

Comment: Le LBU (717) est d'accord avec le TLFi. Ce n'est pas grammaticalement incorrect, ça s'analyse, et c'est bien plus nuancé que ton propos ne le laisse croire.

Comment: @4469766572736974C3A9 Ça s'analyse, bien sûr, comme on analyse « la ligne avec il a vu la faute est la première », mais ce n'est que forcé et on  peut faire de l'analyse de force   comme ça toute la journée (où en fait il n'y a absolument aucune analyse). Pourquoi justifier celle-là plutôt qu'une autre ? Non, quoi qu'en disent les LBU, TlFi et autres mentors, c'est non grammatical.